# Classes with the same interface but different types for a property

Tags: c#, .net, types, interface

I would like to have this kind of design :

```
public interface IDifferentTypes
{
}

public class IntegerType : IDifferentTypes
{
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class StringType : IDifferentTypes
{
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeType : IDifferentTypes
{
    public DateTime value { get; set; }
}
```

but with the property 'value' defined in the interface.

So I can call something like that :

```
IDifferentTypes someInt = GetSomeInt(); // GetSomeInt() returns a IntegerType object
Assert.AreEqual(5, someInt.value);

IDifferentTypes someString = GetSomeString(); // GetSomeString() returns a StringType object
Assert.AreEqual("ok", someString.value);
```

Problem is that the type of value is different for each implementation, what is the best way to deal with that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could define a generic interface (but it will have to be a property, or, more strictly, it can't be a field):

```
public interface IHasValue<T> {
  T Value { get; }
}
```

Where `T` is the type, a placeholder, if you will, and you can do:

```
public class HasStringValue : IHasValue<string> {
  public string Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: An interface can't specify a field; it would need to be a property

Comment: Unfortunately you also then have to specify the closed generic type in code, so you can't generalise the interface between, say, a string and an int - not without having yet another interface that perhaps exposes `object` value.

Comment: but then we have to know at design time what type is required to be returned?

Comment: @Servy : changed for a property for the sake of the example.

Comment: @Servy Indeed, I was held up at work, I've managed to update now.

Comment: If you only have a getter you can make the interface covariant, which would allow you to have a `List<IHasValue<object>>` that has a bunch of the derived types in it.  If you need a setter then the type is invariant and there is no logical way for you to have a collection of `IHasValue` objects of different types.  It's not (just) a limitation of C#, it's that you couldn't ever do anything meaningful while maintaining type safety.

Comment: Thanks Grant Thomas, that looks like the way to go!

Comment: @GrantThomas You wouldn't need to make any change at all other than to add change the first line of code to: `public interface IHasValue<out T>`.  Nothing more.  It already only defines a getter in the interface, and the fact that the implementation defines a setter doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: @Servy : Hi, I tried your idea with `List<IHasValue<object>>` and `out T` but it gives me an error with the int : cannot convert from 'IDifferentTypes<int>' to 'IDifferentTypes<object>'. It is strange because it is working perfectly with the string...

Comment: @ibiza It's because technically `int` doesn't derive from `object`.  You can't use contravariance to box the results, meaning it will only work for classes, not value types.

Comment: @Servy but isn't `int` only an alias for `Int32`, which derives from object? In all cases, is there a way to make it work to have a list that can also accept value types? Thanks!

Comment: @ibiza `int` is an alias for `Int32`.  `Int32` does *not* derive from object.  It is implicitly convertible to object, but that's different.  You'll need to create your own method/wrapper than can turn an `IHasValue<T> where T : struct` into an `IHasValue<object>`.

Comment: @Servy: `Int32` most certainly does, ultimately, derive from `object`. The OP's problem is caused by the fact that C# variance is restricted to reference types.

Comment: @LukeH No, it doesn't.  As I said, it can be implicitly *converted* to `object`, but that conversion involves a boxing operation.  A value type must be boxed in order to become an `object`.  For it to derived from `object` would be to mean no conversion operation is necessary, it could just be treated as an `object` with no actual actions being taken.  The reason C# variance is restricted to reference types is specifically because of the fact that no value types derive from `object`, or anything for that matter.  If they derived from anything then variance could work for them.

Comment: @Servy: The C# spec says this: *"All C# types, including primitive types such as `int` and `double`, inherit from a single root `object` type."* Boxing, unboxing, variance restrictions etc are examples of where the "unified type system" abstraction gets a bit leaky, but that doesn't change the fact that `int` *does*, logically, derive from `object`.

Comment: @LukeH The language attempts to hide the fact that value types do not derive from `object` doesn't change the fact that they truly don't.  Dealing with value types, on the whole, is much easier if you don't think of them as inheriting from object as well.  Were the abstraction layer (i.e. boxing) a much more complete abstraction it might not be harmful to think of value types as inheriting directly from object, but as it stands, it's not (at least always) a good idea.

Comment: @Servy: I think we're both in agreement about what's actually happening behind the scenes; we're just arguing about the terminology.

Comment: @Servy : Do you think it would be possible to update your answer in order to solve my problem with the value types please? Then I would mark your answer as accepted...thanks for your time if you are willing to do so! :)

Comment: @ibiza It's not my answer.  I have no answer.  This is Grant's answer.

Comment: @Servy: All value types derive from `System.ValueType` which in turn derives from `System.Object`, but value-type storage locations do not hold value-type object, nor references to value-type objects; instead they hold hold the same type of information as value-type objects would store.

Comment: @supercat Yes, I know how value types store data.  What does that have to do with whether or not value types derive from `object`?

Comment: @Servy: The *type* `Int32` inherits from `ValueType` (and `Object`), and an object instance of `System.Int32` is an instance of `System.Object`.  The reason a storage location of type `Int32` does not have a reference-preserving cast to `Object` isn't that `Int32` doesn't inherit from `Object`, but rather that `Int32` storage locations don't hold references to `Int32` instances.

Answer (score 6):

Use generics if you can:

```
var someInt = GetSomeInt();
Assert.AreEqual(5, someInt.Value);

var someString = GetSomeString();
Assert.AreEqual("ok", someString.Value);

// ...

public interface IDifferentTypes<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class IntegerType : IDifferentTypes<int>
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

public class StringType : IDifferentTypes<string>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class DateTimeType : IDifferentTypes<DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IDifferentTypes
{
    Object Value { get; set; }
}

class StringType : IDifferentTypes
{
    string _value;

    public Object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }
        set
        {
            _value = value as string;
        }
    }
}
```

But this means that every time you use `StringType.Value` you're going to need to recast it.  You may want to also expose a public accessor of the specific type.  You also may want to add some protections against assigning the wrong type:

```
class StringType : IDifferentTypes
{
    public String StringProperty { get; set; }

    public Object Value
    {
        get
        {
            // works with any type that can auto cast to `Object`
            return StringProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            // Optional
            if( typeof(string) != value.GetType() )
            {
                throw new MyException();
            }

            // works for any nullable type
            StringProperty = value as string;

            // OR

            // throws an exception if conversion fails
            StringProperty = (string)value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not a big fan of your use of the `as` operator in the Value setter.  It hides situations where the developer accidentally sets the wrong type to the property.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the entire design pattern, there is all kinds of issues with setting the wrong type or having to recast the type when you need to access it.  It entirely depends on how you're using it as to if it would be better to have a null assigned or get an exception by using (string)value instead.

Comment: Agreed.  And in terms of maintainability if how to use a class isn't immediately obvious from its definition or signatures, then it will likely be misused thus be very costly.